# How to implement drop_while on mutable iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator, mutable

Is there an efficient way to perform a `drop_while` for mutable iterators?

Using [`.take_while()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) on its own is insufficient because [`TakeWhile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.TakeWhile.html) is lazy:

```
let s = String::from("abcdefg");
let mut it = s.chars();

it.by_ref().take_while(|x| *x != 'c');

println!("{:?}", it.next());
```

This results in a `Some('a')` and the following warning:

```
unused `std::iter::TakeWhile` that must be used
```

This can be fixed by running a `.collect()` which results in the wanted `Some('d')`:

```
let _: String = it.by_ref().take_while(|x| *x < 'c').collect();
```

But, is this the correct approach? Would this not waste resources?

Comment: `iter.find(|x| *x >  'c')` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `skip_while`:

```
let x = it.by_ref().skip_while(|x| *x <= 'c').next();
println!("{:?}", x); // Some('d')
```

which is equivalent to using `find`, with a negated predicate:

```
let x = it.by_ref().find(|x| *x > 'c');
println!("{:?}", x); // Some('d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe most iterator methods are lazy except for [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) which seems to be eager. You can turn your `take_while` into a `drop_while` like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("abcdefg");
    let mut it = s.chars();
    
    it.by_ref().take_while(|x| *x != 'c').for_each(drop);
    
    println!("{:?}", it.next()); // prints "Some('d')"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ba7d850aebf79cf4df89702b5c64bbc)